# Javascript - .push() multiple objects from for loop into multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm running a function that needs to push 16 objects into the `i` position of a multidimensional array.
I am able to push all the data into `var = videoData` using `videoData.push(videoItem)` but I need to end up with a multidimensional array where each nested array contains 16 objects.

```
//variables
videoData       = [],
countries       = ["GB", "ES", "PT", "VN", "ID"],
tags            = ["?tags=english", "?tags=spanish", "?tags=portugues", "?tags=vietnam", "?tags=indonesia"]

//function
function runTask(){
    for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: api_url + tags[i],
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            var sixteenVideos = response.data
            for(var x = 0; x < 16; x++){
                var videoItem = {
                    "keys": {
                        video: "vid" + [x+1]
                    },
                    "values": {
                        url: sixteenVideos[x].slug,
                        thumb: sixteenVideos[x].image,
                        title: sixteenVideos[x].title,
                        desc: sixteenVideos[x].description
                    }
                }
                videoData[i].push([videoItem]);   
            }
            console.log(videoData);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

I expect to end up with...

```
var videoData = [[vid01, vid02....vid16], [vid01, vid02... vid16]]
```

Comment: What is the current output? Is it something like  `[vid01,[vid01...]...]`?

Comment: No, it errors at the moment. It shows ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined```

Comment: That means that whatever `videoitem` is, is undefined. Are you sure you are properly getting the data? What is you `console.log(response);`? Also you are pushing an array of objects like that. Just do `.push(videoItem);`.

Comment: The answer below from Alex Gray works :)

Comment: don't forget to use `const`, `let`, or `var` when declaring variables

Answer (score 1):

`For` loop works synchronously, when executing async operations inside `for` loop, by the time the promises are resolved `for` loop finished it's execution. So value of `i` will have the value from the last loop iteration in every resolved promise.

I don't think `for` loop is really needed here, it can be simpler to create a function that takes a tag and returns a promise which resolves to an array of 16 elements, it may look something like as follows:

```
var videoData = [];
var countries = ["GB", "ES", "PT", "VN", "ID"];
var tags      = ["?tags=english", "?tags=spanish", "?tags=portugues", "?tags=vietnam", "?tags=indonesia"];

var tasks = tags.map(runTask);
Promise.all(tasks).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
});

function runTask(tag) {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: api_url + tag,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  }).then((response) => 
    response.data
      .slice(0, 16)
      .map((video, index) => ({
        "keys": {
          video: "vid" + [index + 1]
        },
        "values": {
          url: video.slug,
          thumb: video.image,
          title: video.title,
          desc: video.description
        } 
      }))
  ).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a loop similar to this to build your multi dimensional array

```
function runTask() {
  var videoData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var country = "Country -" + i;
    var countryArray = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
      var videoItem = country + ", Video -" + x;
      countryArray.push(videoItem);
    }

    videoData.push(countryArray);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of issues with your current code. I'm going to start from scratch in hopes that you can see a better way to approach this. First, axios has many low-level features that you shouldn't concern yourself *every* time you fetch json. Start with something like `fetchJson` -

```
const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  axios
    ( { method: "get"
      , url
      , headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.data)
```

Now when we write `fetchVideos`, we can depend on `fetchJson` and jump right into what we need to do with the parsed response -

```
const apiUrl =
  "https://my.api/"

const fetchVideos = ({ country = "", tag = "" }) =>
  fetchJson(apiUrl + tag)
    .then(apiVideos => apiVideos.map(videoFromApi)) // convert each video
    .then(videos => ({ country, videos })) // build response
```

Instead of relying on separate arrays of `countries` and `tags`, `fetchVideo` takes an *object* input such as -

```
fetchVideos({ country: "GB", tag: "?tags=english" })
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

And it will output an *object* such as -

```
// { country: "GB", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
```

This prevents the need to use crude indexes to link values together. And we kept `fetchVideos` high level by depending on another function `videoFromApi`. This function will convert the API's video response data into the desired shape for our application -

```
const videoFromApi =
  ( { slug = ""
    , image = ""
    , title = ""
    , description = ""
    }
  , id = 0
  ) =>
    Object.assign
      ( { keys: { video: `vid${id + 1}` } }
      , { values:
          { url: slug 
          , thumb: image
          , title: title
          , desc: description
          }
        }
      )
```

Now to tie this all together, we define an array of `requests` and use `Promise.all` to `fetchVideos` for each request. NB, this allows us to know precisely when all API fetches have completed so that our program can move to the next step -

```
const requests =
  [ { country: "GB", tags: "?tags=english" }
  , { country: "ES", tags: "?tags=spanish" }
  , { country: "PT", tags: "?tags=portugues" }
  , { country: "VN", tags: "?tags=vietnam" }
  , { country: "ID", tags: "?tags=indonesia" }
  ]

Promise
  .all(requests.map(fetchVideos))   // fetchVideos for each request
  .then(console.log, console.error) // then log the output, or error if incurred

// [ { country: "GB", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "ES", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "PT", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "VN", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "IN", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// ]
```

To see a functioning demo, expand the snippet below and run it. `axios` has been mocked along with `randomVideos` so that we can simulate an API request -

```js
const apiUrl =
  "https://my.api/"

const requests =
  [ { country: "GB", tags: "?tags=english" }
  , { country: "ES", tags: "?tags=spanish" }
  , { country: "PT", tags: "?tags=portugues" }
  , { country: "VN", tags: "?tags=vietnam" }
  , { country: "ID", tags: "?tags=indonesia" }
  ]

const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  axios
    ( { method: "get"
      , url
      , headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.data)

const fetchVideos = ({ country = "", tag = "" }) =>
  fetchJson(apiUrl + tag)
    .then(apiVideos => apiVideos.map(videoFromApi)) 
    .then(videos => ({ country, videos }))

const videoFromApi =
  ( { slug = ""
    , image = ""
    , title = ""
    , description = ""
    }
  , id = 0
  ) =>
    Object.assign
      ( { keys: { video: `vid${id + 1}` } }
      , { values:
          { url: slug 
          , thumb: image
          , title: title
          , desc: description
          }
        }
      )

// mocks
const axios = async (req = {}) =>
  ({ data: randomVideos(4) })

const randomVideos = (n = 0) =>
  Array.from(Array(n), randomVideo)

const randomVideo = (_, id) =>
  ( { url: `videourl/${id}`
    , image: `images/v${id}.jpg`
    , title: `Video: ${id}`
    , description: `This is video ${1}.`
    }
  )

// run demo
Promise
  .all(requests.map(fetchVideos))
  .then(console.log, console.error)

// [ { country: "GB", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "ES", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "PT", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "VN", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// , { country: "IN", videos: [ v1, v2, v3, ... ] }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do this `"videoData[i].push"` because the position on the array doesn't exist. Yo could solve this using an auxiliar array like this:

```
videoData = []
videoDataAux = []
```

and than:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 16; x++){
            var videoItem = {
                "keys": {
                    video: "vid" + [x+1]
                },
                "values": {
                    url: sixteenVideos[x].slug,
                    thumb: sixteenVideos[x].image,
                    title: sixteenVideos[x].title,
                    desc: sixteenVideos[x].description
                }
            }
            videoDataAux.push([videoItem]);   
        }
videoData[i]=videoDataAux
```